# Wrapping text in text-area using a checkbox

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, word-wrap, jtextarea

I created a dialog box in Swing for editing data. It contains a `JTextArea`, two `JButton` instances (`OK` & `Cancel`) and a `JCheckBox` (`Wrap Text`). What I wanted to do is to have the text in the text area wrapped whenever the user clicks on the check-box. I initially have the text wrapped by using `setLineWrap(true)`.

I am using the following code:

```
    Runnable r1=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("True");
            keyField.setLineWrap(true);
            keyField.requestFocus();
        }
    };

    Runnable r2=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               System.out.println("FALSE");
               keyField.setLineWrap(false);
               keyField.repaint();
               keyField.requestFocus();
            }
     };
    final Thread t1=new Thread(r1) ;
    final Thread t2=new Thread(r2);

    final JCheckBox chkSwing = new JCheckBox("Word Wrap",true);

    chkSwing.addItemListener(
            new ItemListener() {
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                        t1.start();
                    } else if (e.getStateChange() != ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                        t2.start();
                    }
                }
            });

    panel.add(chkSwing);
```

### The Problem

The problem is that once I deselect the check-box, the text gets unwrapped, but again checking the check-box *does not wrap the text again*. The console shows that the thread is being called. How to make the check-box work for setting/unsetting the word wrap behavior of the text-area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to start separate `Thread`s. Even worse, you should not modify Swing components on the non-EDT. See the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial

```
chkSwing.addItemListener(
  new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
       keyField.setLineWrap( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED );
    }
  } );
```

will do it.

Comment: When i wrote the code first, i did not use any thread. I did it pretty much the same way as you suggested. But to no avail. I mean, the same problem persists..

Comment: @AndrewThompson seems I got the tick after all. Only thing I can do is upvote your answer (which I would have done anyway due to the nice picture and the effort to write actual code)

Comment: *"seems I got the tick "*  As it should be - that link is enough to justify the change, even if you had *not* solved the real problem first. ;)  Good choice Sachin. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is working code.  (With a cute animated screenshot with a comment that high-lights something that several answers missed pointing out.)

[image: TextAreaWrapChooser]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

class TextAreaWrapChooser {

    private JTextArea text = new JTextArea(8,30);

    TextAreaWrapChooser() {
        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);

        JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();

        JCheckBox wrap = new JCheckBox("Line wrap", false);
        tb.add(wrap);
        wrap.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            // this method is called on the EDT
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
                boolean doWrap = ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
                System.out.println("Wrap text: " + doWrap);
                text.setLineWrap( doWrap );
            }
        });

        // fill the text area
        try {
            File f = new File("TextAreaWrapChooser.java");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            text.read( fr, f );
        } catch(Exception weTried) {
        }

        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));
        gui.add(tb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        gui.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // construct/start the GUI on the EDT.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TextAreaWrapChooser();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Adrew..thanku so much :) Sorry for not posting the SSCCE. Will do that wenever i post a new question here. BDW...this is just wat i needed... And I will definitely keep in mind your valuable suggestions

Comment: How you did that, please do share, that animated thingy too good

Comment: @nIcEcOw I used the (slightly broken*) [GIFanim](http://pscode.org/gifanim/) for making the final image from two separate screenshots.  *  The 'slightly broken' part is that when coding it, I made the odd decision to pop an option pane error message when there were less than ***3*** frames.  So when making that GIF, I added the pair of frames twice (shrugs).

Comment: Ahha, Many Many Thanks for the information, I had seen that once before i guess, forgot to ask on that thread :-)

Answer (score 4):

Why do you call the wrap set in a separate thread? May be call it in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` ?

Answer (score 4):

In Swing, all the changes you make on graphical components should be done in the EventDispatchThread.

To do so from any thread, the easiest way is to use the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` method.

In your case you want to change the component from an Swing listener callback, meaning you are already in the EventDispatchThread. Thus you can call the `setLineWrap` method from your listener.